# [Cordova][Android] Sockets not connecting when running on release build

Tags: android, angular, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to publish a cordova app on google play store...

However when I run the release build from the store the app does not connect to the sockets.

I am using LaravelEcho with SocketIo client.

- cordova - 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
- angular - 8.1.2
- socket.io - 2.1.4
- laravel-echo - 1.6.1

After I searched the problem I found some results about a permission, but I already have that.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Is it possible to debug the app in the release mode?

### update

This is how I imported the NgxLaravelEchoModule

`NgxLaravelEchoModule.forRoot({
      userModel: 'App.Models.User',
      notificationNamespace: 'App\\Notifications',
      options: {
        broadcaster: 'socket.io',
        host: environment.socketsURL
      }
    }),`

### update

I managed to pint an error message thrown by socket module

`xhr poll error`

Comment: Can you share you socket implementation? also tell is it working in debug APK?

Comment: i updated with the module import also yea it is working when i run on the debug mode..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent hours upon hours searching for the answer to this question (and I know this post is old but perhaps it could help someone). Not one person could answer this. Though, I believe the true answer is that, by default, Android does not like http. Instead, a solution is to use https on whatever your socket.io client is. But that's annoying to setup.

A better solution is to allow http on the Android application. In your AndroidManifest.xml, find "application". It should look like this by default:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Append `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to this to get the following:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Compile your apk and run it on an Android device. And voila! You can now connect to your sockets on the release build.

Answer (score 0):

Server: Make sure that you've set the origin:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const cors = require("cors");

const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

app.use(cors());
```